# Should we allow grammar questions on here?

Tags: discussion, off-topic

I believe that we **should not** allow grammar questions on this site.  It should be a place to discuss writing techniques, styles, etc., but not to have your work copy-edited.

There is already a StackExchange site for English, and the one for German is well-along in the commit phase.  I believe questions of this nature belong on those sites, and not on this one.

What are your thoughts?  Do you agree or disagree and why?

Comment: Agreed with "There is already a StackExchange site for English" - All grammar questions should go there.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I agree with this assessment.  Grammar questions *that reference specific uses of language in specific instances* should be referred to the English SE (and when both of these sites are full sites I think there ought to be an established migration path between the two).

I believe questions on self-editing techniques in general **should** be on topic.  Also perhaps we could allow questions looking for grammar reference manuals.

Answer (score 2):

I was writing up the same question! I agree, grammar is off-topic. However, copyediting itself is about far more than grammar, and we can't exclude it wholesale. (The proposal in Area 51 includes writers and editors.)

Comment: Indeed, but I think specific questions about English grammar should be asked on the English site.

Comment: The topic of copy-editing should be allowed, but copy-editing itself is probably crossing the line.

Comment: @StrixVaria - Putting up a paragraph and asking "please edit this" would be out of bounds, but "what are approaches to take to tell an author they're a lousy writer" or "how can I coordinate chapters with an author" would be legitimate questions. (Something more specific would be nice, of course.)

Answer (score 1):

I would agree on allowing a question if it is specific about a small section (1-2 sentences). If someone is asking whether the grammar can be used, I think that there is value and helping people understand where and when different structures make sense.

Some writers work in a very casual style, and their flaunting of the rules of grammar can work. Allowing them a place to discuss things is a good idea. I can also see value in helping people understand when poor grammar is a problem.

Comment: I believe it should be acceptable for a writer to ask if the grammar he intends to use or has used is either appropriate or correct. This is just another way of helping to improve a person's writing and getting peer feedback.